# Does CameraX support macro focus?

Tags: android, camera, macros, focus, android-camerax

I am currently trying to implement a functionality for macro focus in Android. Both, Camera1 API and Camera2 API offer the possibility for `FOCUS_MODE_MACRO`/`AF_MACRO`.

For CameraX, I found `FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF` which is obviously not the macro focus mode. Does anybody have an idea whether macro focus is supported in CameraX and, if yes, how?